# Reporting Solution for Data Validation Queries

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'd like to get some advice on a reporting situation that I have.  I am working in SQL Server.  I have a ton of data validation queries that I run against a database.  In general, for each query, I return two things -- one is the count of the offending records, and the other is the offending records themselves.

My goal is produce a report that gives the counts of the offending records for all data validation queries (ideally, on one sheet in an Excel workbook) and the offending records themselves (ideally, on separate sheets in an Excel workbook).

How is this best achieved?  That is, what technology is best for this situation?  For example, in the past, I have prototyped the queries in SSMS, copied them into a Windows batch file (and added code to write the results to separate text files), and called the batch file via the sqlcmd utility (using command prompt).  However, I know that other solutions exist (e.g., SSRS).  Would something like SSRS be a better tool for this situation?  I'm hesitant to go the SSRS route, since I'm only giving metrics on one issue (i.e., counts of offending records) and the rest of the report consists of offending records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get closed because it is a matter of opinion, but SSRS would be a good solution for this requirement. I think SSRS is a good fit if you have the following criteria:

- You need to visualize the data in some kind of a table, chart, or graph
- You want to send out automated emails every morning / week / month to a group of users (as opposed to just individual consumption)
- You want to be able to export the report to other formats (excel or pdf) for additional analysis or sharing.

Otherwise, if it's just for you and you currently don't have SSRS running on the server, save yourself the overhead of running another service and just keep doing it in batch files.